# Replace text in the input form and visit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a form for my blog visitors like this:

```
<form name="myform" id="test">
<input type="text" name="url"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

If someone enters a URL: `https://demo.website.com/page/blablabla.html`

It will generate a URL: `https://newwebsite.com/page/blablabla.html`

So the point is: just change `demo.website` be `newwebsite`
Is this possible with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: `'https://demo.website.com/page/blablabla.html'.replace('https://demo.website','https://newwebsite')`

Comment: the full code how?

Comment: What is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$("input[name='url']").on('change', function(e){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace("demo.website.","newwebsite."));
})
```

Comment: how do you expect it to work, on 'submit' event or on 'change' event?

Answer (score 0):

Working code would be somewhat like this

```
<form name="myform" id="test">
<input type="text" name="url" onblur="func(this)" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
    function func(elem){
        var _url = elem.value;
        var finUrl = _url.replace('demo.website','newwebsite');
        console.log(finUrl);
    }
</script>
```